# How to read an external JSON file as a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an external json file which I am using to initialize a js object in a web app (using webpack).

**To read the file im doing this:**

```
var myObject = require('json-loader!constants/myfile.json')
```

The application needs to modify the object over time and occasionally needs to return to the original state. Due to this, I've found this to be the most performant way **to initialize and reinitialize (deep clone) the object:**

```
var clonedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

This approach seems redundant - First load a json object then stringify the object only to load it again.

Is there a way to read the JSON file as a string and then JSON.parse the object (thus omitting the JSON.stringify step)?

Comment: I'd just deep clone the object when you need to (although I'd use a library instead).

Comment: @Dave Newton, I am deep cloning the object when i need to. The issue is the most effective way I've found to deep clone (an object with nested objects) is to JSON.parse the string converted object. So my question is how to skip a step by reading the JSON in as a string.

Comment: By using a deep-cloning library that doesn't deal with strings. This can't possibly be the most important thing in your code though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) to read a file as string:

```
var jsonString = require('raw-loader!constants/myfile.json');
var obj1 = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the file contents first using a blob perhaps.
Get the text content, then use  the JSON.parse(jsonString).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I am too ignorant to keep libraries in my head, and thus I read JSON files with `fs` like this:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var stuff=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("filename","utf8"));
```

And then it is pretty sure that someone could store the intermediate result of `fs.readFileSync()` if they wanted to:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var originaljson=fs.readFileSync("filename","utf8");
var stuff=JSON.parse(originaljson);
```